# Groovy AntBuilder - Specify Java Temp Dir

Tags: java, groovy, directory, tmp, antbuilder

In my Groovy program, I am using Groovy AntBuilder to call the Ant ReplaceRegExp task.

```
def antBuilder = new AntBuilder()
antBuilder.replaceregexp(....)
```

However on Unix, I get the following exception:

```
Could not create tempfile in /tmp
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils.createTempFile(FileUtils.java:941)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ReplaceRegExp.doReplace(ReplaceRegExp.java:353)
```

The UNIX user I use to run the Goovy program does not have permissions for the default java temp directory.
When using Ant directly, I can work around this by specifying the java.io.tmpdir for Ant using ANT_OPTS.

```
export ANT_OPTS="${ANT_OPTS} -Djava.io.tmpdir=/scratch/mydir/tmp"
```

Qs: With Groovy AntBuilder in Groovy code, how can I specify the java.io.tmpdir for AntBuilder?

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would setting `java.io.tmpdir` with [`setProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) or passing `java.io.tmpdir` via `-D` switch, e.g. `-Djava.io.tmpdir=some_path` help?

Comment: Yes, setting java.io.tmpdir with `setProperty` within the Groovy program worked. Still curious however if there is a way to set the tmp dir on the AntBuilder object itself. Maybe there isn't ... but this approach does the job.